# Using Spring, how can I manually fire AuthenticationSuccessHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to provide the user an alternative means of logging in with a token. I already handle authenticating the user in the PreAuthenticationFilter class but then I need to fire my

`AuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess()`

which does a

`super.onAuthenticationSuccess()`

which fires the method in it's base class of

`SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.`

How can I fire the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` from my preauthentication filter? I tried setting the authentication of the `SecurityContextHolder` thinking it would automatically fire off the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` but it does not. This is how I tried to do that:

```
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Username, Password);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work though. So I need to know how to fire the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` from a preauthentication filter.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably be inspired of how the `RememberMeAuthenthicationFilter` works in spring-security. It has a reference to the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`, and calls `onAuthenticationSuccess` manually.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend the PreAuthenticationFilter and overwrite the method successfulAuthentication. There you can trigger your injected success handler.